# Binding combobox with object array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

how to bind array object to combo box in Air application..

i have array of objects from that i need to bind name property to the label field of combobox how to do that ?

var objk:Array=objkparent.children; // it return object collection
  comboBox.dataProvider=objk;
  comboBox.labelField=objk.name;

but its not working how to bind it...?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the elements in objk array have a field called name? I tried the following which seems to work.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[       
            [Bindable]
            private var daStates:Array = [
               { name:"Arizona", label:"AZ" },
               { name:"Tennessee", label:"TN" },
               { name:"New York", label:"NY" }
            ];
    ]]>
</mx:Script>


<mx:Panel layout="absolute" title="Stack Overflow" id="panel" height="100%" width="100%">
    <mx:Form id="daForm">
        <mx:FormHeading label="Just a demo" />
        <mx:FormItem label="Combo Box">
            <mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{daStates}" labelField="name" />
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
</mx:Panel>
```

Also, in general its better to use ArrayCollection rather than Array when binding is involved.